# CAM 5 LASER CUTTER : needing to change the laser tube

Tags: power-supply, laser, tube

My boss and I discovered that one of the laser tube needs to be changed, and when we figured which one needed it, I told him not to touch the red wire, that there may still be power in it. Well he did, needless to say he's not going to do that again.
 I need to know how to safely discharge the power supply, and or, tube. So we can change the tube.

Off the top of my head it's a 20,000 volt power supply with a 100 watt laser tube. I can tell you more on Monday when I get to work

Comment: It's laser and your should read the manual lest someone dies

Comment: Something like a laser cutter should have a *repair manual*.  Read that.

Comment: He's not going to do it again because he is dead?

Comment: @SpehroPefhany - Oh, I'm sure a little tickle from a mere 20 kV cap didn't _kill_ him. Just a little burn, some muscle and/or nerve damage. Nothing to get excited about.

Comment: Sadly, you never find enough candidates to a Darwin award! At least he didn't try to check if the tube was working by looking into the aperture where the beam comes out from. *sigh*

Comment: Probably he has the t-shirt that says "Do not look into laser beam with remaining eye."

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'd love to see that T-shirt! :-D (I know a couple of people to whom it would suit too well!)

Comment: @LorenzoDonati  A T-shirt like that is not hard to design.  We can take a [standard laser warning sign](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/local/safety/laser/laser-symbol.gif) and write the humor underneath.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called a discharge stick, and your best bet is to buy one. (http://www.tomwblack.com/phenix/40400_Discharge_Ground_Sticks.pdf)

If you're hell-bent on doing it quick and cheap, then you can try this.

What you do is take a wooden dowel or fiberglass rod about 1/2 to 1 inch in diameter, and about 18 inches long. At one end you make a series of 10 1M, 1/2 watt resistors, with the lead of the end resistor sticking out. The resistors are epoxied to the rod, and then held in place with tie-wraps. You really want a mechanically strong unit. From the resistor near the center of the rod, solder a wire of a convenient length, say 12 - 18 inches long, and put an alligator clip on it. Put down a rubber mat and stand on it. Have someone who cares about your health (like you) use a meter to verify that the resistor chain from exposed wire to alligator clip is 10M, and not open. Check twice. Connect the alligator clip to chassis ground. Holding the end of the rod in one hand, put the other hand in your pocket. No, I'm not kidding. Now touch the exposed resistor end to your high-voltage connection, and let it sit there for at least a minute.

Keeping the resistor in contact with the HV, have somebody else measure the voltage. Assuming it's good, connect the HV and ground to the meter via secure clips, and monitor the voltage when you remove the resistors. You'll probably see a certain rebound. Now clip a 1k, 1W resistor from HV to ground to bleed of this rebound.

And you should be good to go.

Of course, you want to remove the 1k before you turn the unit back on.

Comment: You can also add a neon bulb in series with the resistor string.  The bulb will light until the voltage drops below the bulb drop-out voltage (less than 100 Vdc).  Note that meter testing the resistor string must be done with the neon bulb NOT in circuit.  You can (and should) also test by applying Mains voltage across the discharge stick and observing the lit neon bulb before relying upon it.

Comment: @DwayneReid - Good suggestion. You can also put a meter across the bottom resistor in the chain. And if you mean "meter testing the resistor chain" to be a resistance check, the neon can stay in, since a standard meter voltage (not a high-resistance tester) will not provide enough voltage to activate the neon bulb.